If we know the even fourier series are we able to find the odd version?
If we have a sequence, call it $a_{n}$ where $n>0$, and we take it as the fourier coeficents of an even function...
$$
F_{e}(x) = \sum^{\infty}_{n=1}a_{n}\cos(2\pi nx)
$$
... and we know the form of $F_{e}(x)$ could we find the form of $F_{o}(x)$ defined below.
$$
F_{o}(x) = \sum^{\infty}_{n=1}a_{n}\sin(2\pi nx)
$$
We know that...
$$
2\int^{1}_{0}F_{e}(x)\cos(2\pi nx)dx = a_{n}
$$
$$
2\int^{1}_{0}F_{o}(x)\sin(2\pi nx)dx = a_{n}
$$
...but I have had trouble being able to extract any information from $F_{o}(x)$ in terms of $F_{e}(x)$. Particulary in such a way that makes $F_{o}(x)$ independent of n. Is there any way to solve for $F_{o}(x)$ in terms of $F_{e}(x)$ or is there a definable relationship between the two functions outside of there fourier series repersentations? Are there any known examples where we know both the even and odd versions of the same fourier coeficents? Any help would be appreaciated.

In general the even and odd terms of a Fourier series are completely unrelated.

From $f_e(x)$ to $f_o(x)$, the Fourier series exponential coefficients are multiplied by $\frac{\operatorname{sgn}(n)}i$: $$F_o[n] = \operatorname{sgn}(n)\cdot \frac{a_{\lvert n\rvert}}{2i} = \frac{\operatorname{sgn}(n)}i\cdot F_e[n], \quad n\in\mathbb Z$$
so in the time domain, $f_o(x)$ may be obtained by the periodic convolution of $f_e(x)$ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sin(2\pi nx)$. But then that sine series doesn't always converge...

@QiaochuYuan I think everyone is misreading the question. The OP is starting with a sequence ${a_n}$ and asking whether there is a relationship between $\sum a_n \cos(2\pi n x)$ and $\sum a_n \sin(2\pi n x)$.

@CheerfulParsnip That's what I understood.

Some remarks, too long for a comment.
We can consider functions on the real line with period $1$.
Let $f_e$ be an even function and $f_o$ an odd function. Suppose both $f_e$ and $f_o$ have period $1$. Let $f:=f_e+f_o$ then
$$a_n:=\int_0^1 f(x)\cos(2\pi nx)dx = \int_0^1 f_e(x)\cos(2\pi nx)dx$$ and $$b_n:=\int_0^1 f(x)\sin(2\pi nx)dx = \int_0^1 f_o(x)\sin(2\pi nx)dx.$$
In particular, we cannot expect there to be any relationship between $a_n$ and $b_n$.
Given any function $f$ with period $1$, let $f_e(x):=\frac{f(x)+f(-x)}{2}$ and $f_o(x):=\frac{f(x)-f(-x)}{2}$. Then $f_e$ is an even function with period $1$ and $f_o$ is an odd function with period $1$. Clearly,  $f=f_e+f_o.$ By the previous observation we cannot expect there to be any relationship between $a_n$ and $b_n$.
Given $a_n$, if you define $F_e(x):=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n\cos(2\pi x)$, then $F_e$ is an even function and $F_o(x):=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n\sin(2\pi x),$ then $F_o$ is an odd function. And $F_e(x)+F_o(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n(\cos(2\pi nx)+\sin(2\pi nx))=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sqrt{2}a_n\sin(2\pi nx +\pi/4).$ This gives some examples of functions where $a_n=b_n.$
